# Multiple Integration methods in CERN ROOT library

Tags: c++, root-framework

I've been converting some old Fortran code to C++ and I've run into a bit of a bind. There's a section that involves the cernlib function DGMLT, Gaussian Quadrature for Multiple Integration, which is defined at http://hep.fi.infn.it/cernlib.pdf

I've been scouring online and I can't find a suitable method in [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/index.html) to replicate this process. The few examples of multiple integration functions I've found (`ROOT::Math::AdaptiveIntegratorMultiDim()` and the like) don't have any code examples.

Basically, I need some sample code for multiple integration, possibly using ROOT.

Comment: Do you want code samples *for the functions you found*, or do you want *different* functions? I don't know either cernlib, ROOT, or much of the math involved, but I find the ROOT library API to be well documented...?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a snippet using `AdaptiveIntegratorMultiDim::Integral`
to compute multidimensional gaussian integrals with dimension
2--15:

```
for(unsigned int dim=2; dim<kMaxSyst; ++dim){
    NdimNormal nDimNormal(dim);
    ROOT::Math::Functor func(nDimNormal,dim);
    ROOT::Math::IntegratorMultiDim im(func);
    volNom = im.Integral(xminNom, xmaxNom);
    volSys = im.Integral(xminSys, xmaxSys);
    cout<<"dim = "<<dim
        <<" : volNom = "<<volNom
        <<" , volSys = "<<volSys
        <<endl;
}
```

The class `NdimNormal` is an N-dimensional function object,
see its definition in the full code here: [gist link](https://gist.github.com/gerbaudo/1e51079021564136f059).
Note that `AdaptiveIntegratorMultiDim::Integral` can only handle
integrals with dimension between 1 and 16. For higher dimensions you might want to consider `gsl`.